# For the following function decide for which numbers $a$ the limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists:

Tags: calculus, limits

For the following function decide for which numbers $a$ the limit $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$$ exists:

$$f(x) = \text{1st number in decimal expansion of } x $$

the solution says that all $a$ not of the form $$n + \frac{k}{10}$$ for integers  $n$ and $k$ can work. I'm trying to reconcile this notion. I personally thought that all values of $a$ would be fine, but are we just taking into consideration all values except for $a$ itself? I mean all values that approach $a$? But with that being the idea, every value can have a decimal representation which would make it difficult for the limit to exist....

Comment: Note this difference: $$ lim_{x-->a} f(x) $$ $$ \lim_{x\to a} f(x) $$ I changed the former to the latter and did some other copy-editing. $\qquad$

Comment: funny, even before I read your comment, the first thing I did was look at the Tex edits you made so I am aware for the future.

Answer (score 1):

What is $\lim_\limits {x\to 2} f(x)$?

If $x$ is on the right side of $2, f(2^+) = 2.$  If $x$ is on the left side of $2,$ e.g. $x=1.9999, f(2^-) = 1.$

$\lim_\limits {x\to 2} f(x)$ does not exist.

Any open ball around 2, will have some margin on both sides of 2.

$\lim_\limits {x\to 2.01} f(x) = 2$

Now we have a little bit of room.  We just make the radius of our open ball less than 0.01.

Where does this leave us?  The limit doesn't exist if $x$ is an integer in $[-10,10].$  It exists at $11,$ but not at $20.$

What would be an expression that generalizes where the limit does not exist?

How about, $k 10^n$ with n as a natural number and k as an integer in in $(-10,10)$

Comment: I think I see your point. Using your example, the reason the limit would not exist at an integer is because of the "0.999999 idea", but why would that affect $0.1$ or $0.02$? both of those numbers would equal $0$ under the definition of this function....

Comment: That is a matter of how I interpreted definition of the function (which in hindsight may not have been been incorrect).  I was thinking that f(x) took on the left most non zero element.  You can strike that line, $k10^n$ would still be correct, except than $n$ is a natural number and not an integer.